# OneSignal sending to targeted users

Tags: android, ios, onesignal

I'm planning to send push notification to targeted users. I understand that this can be achieved by targeting by the player ids. But going for this approach would require my database to introduce dependency with OneSignal which is something that I'm trying to avoid.

I'm thinking is it possible to target players by username. What I mean when the app initializes it would update OneSignal saying that 'my username is user1' and when the server sends out notification it can target 'user1' (again, without using the player id approach).

The closest way that I could think of is tagging where the user could register themselves with username as the tag and server could target the user by using the tags. But from the documentation it seems like with this approach we can only target 200 users at once which is not feasible to me as well - I might be sending to thousands of users.

Any advice?

Comment: i'm also interested in knowing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, tags are the best way to achieve this without storing OneSignal IDs.

Although this is limited to 200 at a time, you can make multiple API calls to deliver to a larger number of total users. OneSignal's average API response time for this method is below 50 milliseconds, so this method will allow you to reach 4,000 users per second if you make the API calls in sequence.

Comment: any reason why we have the limit of 200 tags at a time?

Comment: @JohnDoe This limit exists for performance reasons on our side due to the sophistication available using tags (since you can use =, >, <, and != operators on them). We plan on further increasing this limit in the future.

Answer (score 1):

OneSignal is a wrapper to Firebase Cloud Messaging or FCM (previously Google Cloud Messaging or GCM) on Android. If you don't want to rely on OneSignal internal device ID (or Player ID), **you could still use FCM/GCM Registration IDs directly** (also called push tokens) to target users with notifications. But in that case, you still have to store new IDs on your servers (instead of using your owns) and more importantly, you'll have to deal with FCM/GCM tokens complexity by yourself (managing errors, canonicals etc.)..

A better solution would be to **use a third party like [Batch.com](https://batch.com)** (disclosure: I'm a co-founder). We allow developers to provide their own User ID (it's called a **Custom User ID**, you can [set it from the app code](https://batch.com/doc/android/custom-data/custom-user-id.html#_custom-user-identifier)) and then use it with our [Transactional API](https://batch.com/doc/api/transactional.html) to send push notification to one or more users (recipients can be push tokens, Batch installation IDs or your own User/Custom ID).